# Object reference Error when test executes sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I have got a test to assert then when my application generates an application number(RHI), it asserts that the generated number on the final page is equal to the number in the db;

```
public void AssertRHINumberFromDB()
{
    string rhiFromText = GenerateRHINumberIntoTextFile();
    string query = "Select RHINumber from RHI.Application where RHINUMBER = 'rhiFromText'";
    var rhiFromDB = Helper.ExecuteScalar(query);

    Assert.Equals(rhiFromDB.Contains("RHINUMBER"), rhiFromText);
}
```

Though, when the `ExecuteScalar` method goes, I am hit with Object Reference Error and `rhiFromDB` is returning null.

**relevant code:**

```
public string GenerateRHINumberIntoTextFile()
{
    var rhiPath = AppDriver.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#main-content>div>p:nth-child(2)>b"));
    string generatedRHI = rhiPath.GetAttribute("innerText");
    Helper.DeleteTextFilesAfterThreeMinutes();
    Helper.WriteTextFile("TestFile1", generatedRHI);

    return generatedRHI;
}

public static string ExecuteScalar(string command, SqlParameter[] parms = null)
{
    using (ISQLService sql = new SQLService(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"])))
    {
        return sql.ExecuteScalar(command, parms);
    }
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: It sounds like the database query isn't finding anything.  I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, I guess it's up to you to define how you want your logic to handle that scenario.  If that scenario shouldn't happen and it should always find a record then check your database and see if that record is there.

Comment: Also, what does this even mean?:  `Assert.Equals(rhiFromDB.Contains("RHINUMBER"), rhiFromText);`  You're trying to compare a boolean with a string.

Comment: right, haven't fixed that bit because I've been focused on getting it past the executescalar part

Comment: According to documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` when no record is found.  So you'll either need to ensure that the record is there before running this code or handle `null` in the code.